# Holomorphic automorphisms on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Gong Sheng's [Concise Complex Analysis](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Concise-Complex-Analysis-Sheng-Gong/dp/9810243790), where it introduced the concept of automorphism first in Ch2.5:

> Let $U$ be a region contained in $\mathbb C$. The group of holomorphic
> automorphisms on $U$ is defined as follows:
>
> Suppose $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function defined on $U$. If $f(z)$
> maps $U$  one-to-one and holomorphically to itself, then $f(z)$ is
> called a holomorphic  automorphism on $U$. All of the holomorphic
> automorphisms on $U$ form a  group, called the group of holomorphic
> automorphisms of $U$ and is denoted  by $Aut( U)$.

So apparently here automorphism is only a bijection, not preserving any operation on $\mathbb C$, i.e. if $a(z) \in Aut(U)$ and $z_1, z_2 \in U$, it's not required to have $a(z_1+z_2) = a(z_1) + a(z_2)$ etc.

Then, in Ch3.4, to find the group of holomorphic automorphisms on $\mathbb C$, denoted as $Aut(\mathbb C)$, it says:

> Let $a(z) \in Aut(\mathbb C)$. Then $a(z)$ maps $\infty$ to $\infty$. Since the map is an automorphism, it is one-to-one.
> **Thus, $z = \infty$ is a simple pole of $a(z)$**.  According to the preceding result, $a(z)$ must be
> a polynomial of degree  one, $a(z) = az + b$,
> where $a,b \in \mathbb C$ and $a\ne 0$. Conversely, it is easy to  see
> that $az + b \in Aut(\mathbb C)$ if $a, b \in \mathbb C$ and
> $a \ne 0$. So $Aut(\mathbb C)$ consists of all  linear transformations $az+b$
> with $a, b \in \mathbb C$ and $a\ne 0$. In other words, every
> element of $Aut(\mathbb C)$ is the composition of a translation
> $\alpha(z) = z + b$ and a  dilation $\alpha ( z) = az$.

I'm confused in the bold line

> $z = \infty$ is a simple pole of $a(z)$

This actually means

$$a(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_{-n}}{z^n} + c_1 z$$

But why? could $a(z)$ near $\infty$ has power higher than 1, or even $\infty$?

Comment: it would not be (locally) injective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much machinery you've already seen, but here is an approach (eg this is how it's treated in Henri Cartan's text). A-priori, since $a$ is holomorphic, there are only two possibilities for the behavior of the function $a$ near $\infty$:

1. Either $\infty$ is an isolated essential singularity of $a$.
2. Or $\infty$ is not an isolated essential singularity of $a$ (and hence $a$ is a polynomial).

We can now use Weierstrass's theorem which says that the image under a holomorphic map of any neighborhood of an isolated essential singularity is dense in the complex plane. We use this theorem as follows: let $D$ be the open unit disc. Then, the image $a(D)$ is a non-empty open set in $\Bbb{C}$. The set $U=\Bbb{C}\setminus\overline{D}=\{z\in\Bbb{C}:\,\, |z|>1\}$ is an open neighborhood of the point at infinity, so $a(U)$ is dense in the complex plane by the theorem. However, we have $a(D)\cap a(U)=\emptyset$, contradicting the fact $a(U)$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$. Therefore, option (1) is not possible.

Comment: thank, now i see it.. then dense part of Weierstrass theorem I have seen, but didn't realize it's implicitly used.

Comment: @athos just extra FYI: Weierstrass' theorem is relatively simple to prove, but it can be improved much further. Picard's big theorem tells us that the image of any open neighborhood of an isolated essential singularity is either $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ minus a single point... but Picard's theorem for this simple result is I think overkill.

Comment: that's in Ch 5, i'm inching toward it :)